# MathJax doesn't render the "less-than sign"

Tags: javascript, mathml, mathjax, parsing-error

I'm trying to display the less-than sign using MathJax to render MathML input... currently working on Firefox but will be expanding to other browsers. I have tried displaying the sign in different variations:

- `<`
- `&lt;`
- `&#x003C;`

But I get the following error:

```
Error parsing MathML: not well-formed Line Number 18, Column 13: <mo><</mo> ------------------------------------------------------^
```

I'm using the following MathML code:

```
<math mode="display" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
 <mpadded height="+.7lex">
  <mrow>
   <mo>&#x003C;</mo>
  </mrow>
 </mpadded>
</math>
```

Any idea why this might be happening? I've read that this might be a bug with MathJax, but I also tried doing this using other tags but no luck. I'm also pretty sure I'm using the latest version of MathJax.

Thanks,
Hristo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in MathJax that was fixed in the SVN version 580, which hasn't been included in a packaged version yet.  You may want to get a current SVN copy of MathJax rather than one of the ZIP files.  The fix will be included in the next release of MathJax

Answer (score 0):

I am using the older, beta version of MathJax, but did find a working example on my site. It uses the code `<mo>&lt;</mo>`.

Could it be that you need to use the math operator (`mo`) tag instead of the text (`mtext`) tag?

Comment: That was a mistake on my end... I am actually using the `<mo>` tag, as noted in the error message

Comment: Ah, sorry for overlooking that.